# meteor Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault'

Tags: meteor

Having this error:

```
W20180804-11:57:23.254(1)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault'
W20180804-11:57:23.254(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
W20180804-11:57:23.254(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
W20180804-11:57:23.254(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (/home/inu/workspace/meteor/lff3/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:288:32)
W20180804-11:57:23.254(1)? (STDERR)     at makeInstallerOptions.fallback (packages/modules-runtime.js:653:18)
W20180804-11:57:23.254(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:16)
W20180804-11:57:23.255(1)? (STDERR)     at livedata_connection.js (/home/inu/workspace/meteor/lff3/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp-client.js:147:30)
W20180804-11:57:23.255(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7)
W20180804-11:57:23.255(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180804-11:57:23.255(1)? (STDERR)     at namespace.js (packages/ddp-client/common/namespace.js:1:300)
W20180804-11:57:23.255(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7)
```

Already tried installing latest babel runtime with no success.

```
meteor npm install @babel/runtime@latest
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been traced [in the forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/error-cannot-find-module-babel-runtime-helpers-builtin-interoprequiredefault/44944/7) as an incompatibility **with the latest version** of `@babel/runtime`.
Change the corresponding line in the package.json file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
```

and then do

```
meteor npm install
```

Comment: That's actually disgusting, isn't there any other solution ?

Comment: Probably a bug in the latest release of babel and/or meteor. https://forums.meteor.com/t/error-cannot-find-module-babel-runtime-helpers-builtin-interoprequiredefault/44944

Comment: Fixed a gatsby.js upgrade bug for me. a bit of a hack but I'm back up and running. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Am using "react-native": "0.57.1" 
I come across it today and I running

"$ npm add @babel/runtime"

fixed it

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution for now . Because meteor (1.7.0.3) creates app with

```
"@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51"
```

So, We have to update the version.

`npm i babel@latest` should work but its not working right now, it's showing the same error as before, so for now this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error when I installed version 7.0.0-beta.56. I figured it was a development bug, since it was not more than 2 hours since they had released this new version. So I followed up and saw that the `builtin/` folder did not exist, (this folder should be inside the `helpers/` folder) and the files that the `builtin/` folder should contain were at the same level, that is, in the `helpers/` folder, so the easiest solution I found was to create `builtin/` folder inside `helpers/` folder and move or copy the contents of the `helpers/`folder inside `helpers/builtin/`.

I hope that this will be helpful for those who want to continue with this version.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the above problem and I solved it simply by running the following command;

```
meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime@latest
```